# Connection to Azure SQL from Java

Tags: azure-sql-database, jdbc

I try to connect to Azure SQL with MS JDBC driver:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class ExampleSQLJDBC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Setting.
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER.database.windows.net:1433;database=DATABASE;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;";
        String user = "USER@SERVER";
        String pass = "PASSWORD";

        // Declare the JDBC object.
        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            // Establish the connection.
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, user, pass);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Broken pipe ClientConnectionId:742ba7b5-43bb-441b-8e8d-bbb9dc5fa8ce".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2226)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1756)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1803)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1454)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1285)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:700)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1131)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at run.ExampleSQLJDBC.main(ExampleSQLJDBC.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Interestingly, I can connect to the database from the same computer with Navicat. Hence, the problem should not be in the setting of firewalls.

Metadata:

- Server: Azure V12
- Driver: 6.0 (sqljdbc42.jar)
- JRE: 1.8.0_72-b15 (from Oracle)
- _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djsse.enableCBCProtection=false
- security.provider.1: sun.security.provider.Sun
- OS: OS X 10.11.5

How can I connect to Azure SQL from Java?